# PHP curl post login details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I try to login on axs.com using PHP curl but my script doesn't work.
I want small help to auth this page via PHP.

Is there error in my code?

```
$username = 'aUsername';
$password = 'aPassword';
$loginUrl = 'https://www.axs.com/login_check';


    /* EDIT EMAIL AND PASSWORD */
    $EMAIL      = $username;
    $PASSWORD   = $password;


    function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $cookie=NULL, $p=NULL)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        if ($p) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
        }
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    $a = cURL($loginUrl,true,null,"_username=$EMAIL&_password=$PASSWORD");
    preg_match('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$a,$b);
    $c = cURL($loginUrl,true,null,"_username=$EMAIL&_password=$PASSWORD");
    preg_match_all('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$c,$d);
    for($i=0;$i<count($d[0]);$i++)
        $cookie.=$d[1][$i].";";
    /*
    NOW TO JUST OPEN ANOTHER URL EDIT THE FIRST ARGUMENT OF THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION.
    TO SEND SOME DATA EDIT THE LAST ARGUMENT.
    */
    echo cURL("http://www.axs.com/",null,$cookie,null);
    ?>
```

Is this possible on this web site?

Comment: Where did you get the cookie from ? If you're not running this from http client (eg. running from command line) `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` won't be what you think it is.

Comment: Do you get an error? So yes, which? And which http status?